# How to Combine two controllers and then Action in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am making an eCommerce website it has 
**Home Controller** 
**Categories Controller**
**Products Contoller**

Now i want is when i click on Categories route should be like this

```
www.domain.com/Categories/
```

when i click on Products route should be like this

```
www.domain.com/Products/
```

And when i go to products like phones,pendrive, or TV the route should go like

```
 www.domain.com/Categories/Products/pendrive
```

just because pendrive come from **Products** and Products comes from **Categories** 
so i want to combine two controllers so i can get the required route

Tried something like this but didn't worked

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default1",
                url: "Categories/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a route with same constraints like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Product",
                url: "Categories/Product/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
```

Just make sure this is registered before the default route.

Comment: so it means I can add more than one controller to get a perfect url. Can you explain me what does the Maproute name i.e "Product" matters is it compulsory to have a same name as a controller.

Comment: @VivekSharma you still have one controller and it's the productcontroller. First parameter is just the route name. I changed it to make it more descriptive. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @VivekSharma this route will only work the urls that starts with /categories/product.  they are hardcoded in the template.

Comment: thank you so much @ufuk i will try it and w'll come back to you ;)